# How to take input in an array + PYTHON?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and want to read keyboard input into an array. The python doc does not describe arrays well. Also I think I have some hiccups with the for loop in Python.

I am giving the C code snippet which I want in python:

C code:

```
int i;

printf("Enter how many elements you want: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

printf("Enter the numbers in the array: ");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[raw_input](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input) is your helper here. From documentation -

> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output
>   without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input,
>   converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns
>   that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised.

So your code will basically look like this.

```
num_array = list()
num = raw_input("Enter how many elements you want:")
print 'Enter numbers in array: '
for i in range(int(num)):
    n = raw_input("num :")
    num_array.append(int(n))
print 'ARRAY: ',num_array
```

P.S: I have typed all this free hand. Syntax might be wrong but the methodology is correct. Also one thing to note is that, `raw_input` does not do any type checking, so you need to be careful...

Comment: would you please explain the first line only

Comment: what first line? I have added more info to my answer. what exacytly you dont understand?

Comment: I can write like this also:

num_array=[]  instead of num_array = list() 

I dont know the list() method thats why asking waht it will do ?

Comment: its the same! you can write either way...

Comment: Although accepted, this does not answer the question above. OP didn't want to print "num:" every time. @light94 has given a correct(and shorter) answer below.

Answer (score 24):

You want this - enter N and then take N number of elements.I am considering your input case is just like this

```
5
2 3 6 6 5
```

have this in this way in python 3.x (for python 2.x use `raw_input()` instead if `input()`)

#### Python 3

```
n = int(input())
arr = input()   # takes the whole line of n numbers
l = list(map(int,arr.split(' '))) # split those numbers with space( becomes ['2','3','6','6','5']) and then map every element into int (becomes [2,3,6,6,5])
```

#### Python 2

```
n = int(raw_input())
arr = raw_input()   # takes the whole line of n numbers
l = list(map(int,arr.split(' '))) # split those numbers with space( becomes ['2','3','6','6','5']) and then map every element into int (becomes [2,3,6,6,5])
```

Answer (score 15):

If the number of elements in the array is not given, you can alternatively make use of list comprehension like:

```
str_arr = raw_input().split(' ') //will take in a string of numbers separated by a space
arr = [int(num) for num in str_arr]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
data = []
n = int(raw_input('Enter how many elements you want: '))
for i in range(0, n):
    x = raw_input('Enter the numbers into the array: ')
    data.append(x)
print(data)
```

Now this doesn't do any error checking and it stores data as a string.

Comment: Thanks Taylor , unfortunately with this low balance I can't upvote your answer :(

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = []
elem = int(raw_input("insert how many elements you want:"))
for i in range(0, elem):
    arr.append(int(raw_input("Enter next no :")))
print arr
```